# How to get rid of zsh directory text while in venv?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I use zsh in Terminal and right now it looks like this (text covered up for privacy's sake):
[image]

As you can see, the line is formatted like so:

```
(venv) <username> <directory> <commands>
```

But I'd rather the format be more like:

```
(venv) <commands>
```

b/c the `<username> <directory>` lines are too long and take up too much space.

Is there any way to remove the long directory and username lines?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I've never played with Zsh's prompt (thanks to a variety of themes) but I'm pretty sure this would help: [zsh - Prompt Expansion - Conditional Substrings in Prompts](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts)

Comment: More information about Zsh theme or framework would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most `Zsh` prompt themes are configurable and allow option to add/remove sections, Can't identify your `Zsh` prompt theme.

If your theme doesn't have option for that, You can remove the relevant section from theme file. Location of the prompt theme file depends on the Zsh framework/Plugin manager.

- To remove [username information](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Login-information), Remove the section dealing with `%n`. Sometimes host information is also associated with the same section, Then you might want to remove `%m` or `%M` from prompt sections.
- To disable [directory information](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state),  Remove `%~` or `%d` section.